# reason for ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

Tags: plsql, clob

I have below code

```
DECLARE

      tmp_ CLOB := empty_clob();

   BEGIN

      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Test 4: Set CLOB "A" and then overwrite with empty_clob():');

      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('   Expected: <PARENT><VALUE></VALUE></PARENT>');

      in_ := Plsqlap_Record_API.New_Record('PARENT');

      Plsqlap_Record_API.Set_Value(in_, 'VALUE', TO_CLOB('A'));

      Plsqlap_Record_API.Set_Value(in_, 'VALUE', tmp_);

      Plsqlap_Record_API.To_Xml(xml_, in_);

      Plsqlap_Record_API.Clear_Record(in_);

      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('   Result:   ' || xml_);

   EXCEPTION 

      WHEN OTHERS THEN

          Dbms_Output.Put_Line('   Result:   ' || SQLERRM);

   END;
```

---

**result**

> Test 4: Set CLOB "A" and then overwrite with empty_clob():
>   Expected:     Result:   ORA-22275:
>   invalid LOB locator specified

Comment: Please make sure to visit the SO [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Try to initialise the clob like this:

`dbms_lob.createtemporary(tmp_, true);`

instead of this:

`tmp_ CLOB := empty_clob();`

Comment: @user3235283 you are welcome. don't forget to up-vote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare tmp_ CLOB := empty_clob();

As it is an implementation restriction of DBMS_LOB.

According to the oracle documentation: For the successful completion of DBMS_LOB subprograms, you must provide an input locator that represents a LOB that already exists in the database tablespaces or external file system

You can refer to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66616

As suggested by Plirkee it is a valid to declare temporary procedure parameters